# ValueError: probabilities are not non-negative in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Code:

```
def select(population, fitness_arr):
    total = 0
    probability = []
    arr2 = fitness_arr
    for i in arr2:
        total += i
    
    for i in arr2:
        probability.append(i/total)
    print(probability)
    c = np.random.choice(a=arr, size=1, replace=True, p=probability)
    return c

#example values

population = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
fit_level = [-355, 0, 6167, 26, 526, 740, 315]

select(population, fit_level)
```

Again, it is running properly when:

`population = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]` and `fit_level = [6968, 6313, 766, 6773, 355, 1095, 6848]`

Traceback:
`File "h:/Study/CSE/422/Lab/Lab 2_422/1.py", line 103, in <module>    print(select(population, fit_level)) File "h:/Study/CSE/422/Lab/Lab 2_422/1.py", line 89, in select       c = np.random.choice(a=arr, size=1, replace=True, p=probability)   File "mtrand.pyx", line 930, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.choice ValueError: probabilities are not non-negative`

What can I do about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first entry for `fitness` is -355, so the probability would be negative? Not very sure what is the aim of the code above and what else you can do besides ensure all of the entries in `fitness1` is positive

Comment: Well, this is a code from the Genetic Algorithm of AI and the aim of the code is to select a random population to generate a new generation of the population which will provide more weight to ones that have a high fitness score than before. And the probability will obviously be in between 0 to 1.

Comment: The probability will not "obviously be in-between 0 and 1" if you have a negative fitness, and your probs are just fitness/total... The probability will be negative as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve:

As [@xdurch0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9393102/xdurch0) mentioned in the comment of this post, *if you have a negative fitness, the probability will be negative as well.*

And it was actually the problem.

Negative fitness is invalid for my problem which I did not notice earlier.

A basic sense is the probability of something will be ranged in between 0 (not possible) and 1 (possible). So, if the value is less than 0, then the probability is invalid. So please do make sure and crosscheck if the probability value you get is really valid (should not be) or not.

It can be fixed by making that negative value to 0 too. (depends on your problem statement and approach of solving the problem)